# Is it good to put each directive in separate file Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have about 10 directives and they are pretty complicated. Today I use one file only `directives.js`.

Is there some performance penalty if I'll put each directive to separate file for better maintenance?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript itself doesn't care where the code comes from. But JavaScript code has to be loaded by the browser. Making 10 HTTP requests to load 10 files is obviously slower than making 1 HTTP request to load the equivalent code.

But that's not a good reason to put everything in a single file. You should make one file for each component to make the code maintainable and easy to find. But the build procedure of your application should concatenate and minify the JavaSript files into a single file for production, so that a single file is used by the actual application.

Grunt and Gulp are two good build tools to do that, and much more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a performance penalty for the client if it has to load every file individually. There are, however, server-side techniques to mitigate this, such as [ASP.NET's script bundling](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification), [Grunt's building](http://gruntjs.com/) and many many more, that bundle several JavaScript files into one file for the client.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should put your directives in separate files. This will cause performance degradation  if used as is, however by using build tools like Grunt you can concatenate and minify whole of your app into a single JS file.